# With BibLatex, how do I make the fontsize of the bibliography smaller?

Tags: biblatex, fontsize

I use `biblatex` and `\printbibliography` to add a bibliography at the end of my document. I would like the references in a smaller fontsize than the document's default.

`{\small \printbibliography}` does not work. It merely shrinks the space right above `"References"`.

A minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}

\bibliography{library}

\begin{document}

Al lot fo atextas ljfa slkafj se je kfjaeijfa sdjf aiewjmfcajef studies~\cite{Savit1999,Nowak2004}

{\small \printbibliography}

\end{document}
```

It assumes you have following BibTex file, named `library.bib`:

```
@article{Savit1999,
author = {Savit, Robert and Manuca, Radu and Riolo, Rick},
doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.82.2203},
issn = {0031-9007},
journal = {Physical Review Letters},
number = {10},
pages = {2203--2206},
publisher = {American Physical Society},
title = {{Adaptive Competition, Market Efficiency, and Phase Transitions}},
url = {http://link.aps.org/doi/10.1103/PhysRevLett.82.2203},
volume = {82},
year = {1999}
}
@article{Nowak2004,
author = {Nowak, Martin A. and Sigmund, Karl},
doi = {10.1126/science.1093411},
issn = {1095-9203},
journal = {Science},
number = {5659},
pages = {793--799},
pmid = {14764867},
publisher = {AAAS},
title = {{Evolutionary dynamics of biological games}},
url = {http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/14764867},
volume = {303},
year = {2004}
}
```

Comment: `\AtNextBibliography{\small}` or in the preamble `\AtBeginBibliography{\small}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: It works, thanks! Why don't you provide it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: See also [How to change font size for bibliography?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329/35864), [Biblatex: Changing the font of citation-marks and the references?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6953/35864)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce font size of bibliography; overfull bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203764/reduce-font-size-of-bibliography-overfull-bibliography)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Use `\AtNextBibliography{\small}` or in the preamble `\AtBeginBibliography{\small}`

Comment: One could also use `\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\small}` to reduce the font size for all bibliographies.

Comment: @moewe Do you want to add your comment as answer? I'd be happy to vote up.

Answer (score 34):

If you want to change the font size for all bibliographies in your document it is preferable to redefine `\bibfont` instead of hooking into `\AtBeginBibliography`.

```
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\small}
```

That is because `\bibfont` is used to measure the label lengths for the margin in a numeric bibliography. See [Biblatex/Biber \AtNextBibliography and \fontsize{}{}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474994/35864) for an example where that becomes important. (If you make the bibliography font size smaller, you may only see an excessively large margin. But if you make the font size larger, the alignment might no longer be as nice.)

Comment: Why is `\normalfont` needed there? I am just curious (and I'm not an texpert).

Comment: @CyriacAntony In many cases it probably is not necessary. The redefinition here is based on the original definition from `biblatex.def`, which has `\newcommand*{\bibfont}{\normalfont\normalsize}`. In any case it makes sure that most local font settings don't affect `\printbibliography`.