# Biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am using biblatex and currently my bibliography also displaces the title of the publication. For example

[1] Ingrid de Geer. ‘Earl, Saint, Bishop, Skald – and Music. The Orkney Earldom of the Twelfth Century. A Musicological Study’. PhD thesis. Uppsala: Uppsala Universitet, 1985.

I would like my bibliography to

- Not show the title; for example: [1] Ingrid de Geer, PhD thesis. Uppsala: Uppsala Universitet, 1985.
- Have a smaller font for bibliography entries in comparison to the rest of the text.
  Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=numeric-comp, refsection=chapter]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,worman}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Dolor}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:a,pines}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Sit}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,cicero,companion}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Styles like `biblatex-phys` and some of the `biblatex-chem` family have options to turn off the title of `@article` entries (usually called `articletitle`). So one of those styles could be your first try. The handling of titles for PhD theses differs between said styles, so you could experiment with the different options. For point two have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/203764/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/329/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/205432/35864 (I'd say the `\bibfont` solution is the best solution for `biblatex`).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested above in the comment, by using style = phys, and \AtNextBibliography{\footnotesize}, I found the solutions to my questions.

```
\documentclass[british]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,style=phys,%
articletitle=false,biblabel=brackets,%
chaptertitle=false,pageranges=false,%
refsection=chapter,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\chapter{Lorem}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,worman}

\AtNextBibliography{\footnotesize} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Dolor}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{knuth:ct:a,pines}
\AtNextBibliography{\footnotesize} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]

\chapter{Sit}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{sigfridsson} dolor \autocite{geer,cicero,companion}
\AtNextBibliography{\footnotesize} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```