# How to reduce font size of only the citation marks when using natbib in Beamer or LaTeX?

Tags: beamer, natbib, fontsize

I would like to reduce the size of the actual citation marks (that you get as a result of `cite{key}`) and make it half of the size of the regular font. Is this possible? I am using `\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}` and `\usepackage{natbib}`. I have tried the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/256886/biblatex-reduce-font-size-citation-mark):

```
\renewcommand*{\citesetup}{%
\tiny
\biburlsetup
\frenchspacing}
```

but I get an error `\citesetup undefined` probably because I am using `natbib`. Note: I don't care about the font size in the bibliography. Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{frame}
Lorem ipsum \citep{jon90} % I would like this citation to be 50 percent smaller
\end{frame}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)]{jon90}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you help us and provide a compilable MWE?

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack would be to add your desired font to the definition of `\citep`. In the following example, I added `\tiny`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand\citep
{\begingroup\tiny\NAT@swatrue\let\NAT@ctype\z@\NAT@partrue
    \@ifstar{\NAT@fulltrue\NAT@citetp}{\NAT@fullfalse\NAT@citetp}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{frame}
Lorem ipsum \citep{jon90} % I would like this citation to be 50 percent smaller
\end{frame}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem[Jones et al.(1990)]{jon90}
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. An even more robust (though less elegant) approach would be to encase every citation command -- hopefully, there won't be too many of them in a `beamer` document! -- in a `{\tiny ... }` wrapper... E.g., `... {\tiny\citep{jon90}} ...`.

Comment: ```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{citecolor}{gray}{0.4}
\let\oldcite\cite
\renewcommand{\cite}[1]{{\footnotesize\color{citecolor}\oldcite{#1}}}
```
I am using the above. Is it non-robust?

Comment: @HappyFace If you have a new question, you should ask a new question