# Deactivate oldstyle figures in the bibliography

Tags: biblatex, osf

I use oldstyle figures in the body text and also for the references. In the bibliography, however, the years, editions, volumes and issues do not look good as OSF. How can I deactivate these for the bibliography? Please have a look at the MWE, this is about "1972".

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Labov1972,
        Address = {Philadelphia},
        Author = {William Labov},
        Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
        Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
        Year = {1972}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\begin{document}
    Example citation \cite{Labov1972}. 
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand\rmdefault{ppl}` before the bibliography will change all numbers. If you need more specific changes you will have to add that to the various biblatex field formats.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have an example of this? In particular, I would like to achieve that only the title information is written with upright numbers and not the references [1], [2], etc. as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed (as mentioned by Ulrike in a comment) switching to `ppl` (Palatino with regular numbers) will help. You can do that by redefining `\rmdefault`, but another option is to redefine `\bibfont` as in [Biblatex: Changing the font of citation-marks and the references?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6953/biblatex-changing-the-font-of-citation-marks-and-the-references).

In order to keep the oldstyle figures for the citation label you can locally change back to `pplj` inside the BibLaTeX field `labelnumberwidth` which formats the citation label, as in [Removing brackets from biblatex references for lncs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171567/removing-brackets-from-biblatex-references-for-lncs).

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Labov1972,
        Address = {Philadelphia},
        Author = {William Labov},
        Publisher = {University of Pennsylvania Press},
        Title = {Sociolinguistic Patterns},
        Year = {1972}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[osf]{mathpazo}
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\fontfamily{ppl}\selectfont}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\fontfamily{pplj}\selectfont[#1]}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
Example citation \cite{Labov1972}. Old-style figures in numbers: 1972, [1].
    
Comparison with mathpazo in text and ppl in bibliography:\\[1cm]
\normalfont\frenchspacing
\noindent[1]\quad William Labov. \textit{Sociolinguistic Patterns.} Philadelphia: University of Pennsylvania Press, 1972.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works great. As always, I am very impressed by your expertise and helpfulness.